# How to write a c# console application to split text files into multiple files with number of rows indicated by user

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have written a few lines of code to create a c# console application to split a text file into multiple files using the input from the user. 
This divides the file into lines of 20000 each. I want a user to be able to choose.

I want it to prompt a question 
"How many lines per file would you like to have?"

For a scenario in which a user has a text file with 200000 lines and wants 1000 lines per file. It will divide the text file into multiples with 1000 lines each. Also another user can want 500 lines per file.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\COURE-TECH\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\dnd.txt";

            var fileSuffix = 0;
            int lines = 0;
            Stream fstream = File.OpenWrite($"{fileName}" + (++fileSuffix) + ".txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fstream);

            using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("How many lines per file would you like to have?");
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out lines))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer value!");
                    lines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    lines++;
                    if (lines!=0)
                    {
                        sw.Close();
                        fstream.Close();
                        lines = 0;
                        fstream = File.OpenWrite($"{fileName}{(++fileSuffix) + ".txt"}");
                        sw = new StreamWriter(fstream);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value");
                    }
                }
            }

            sw.Close();
            fstream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

I expect a prompt question "How many lines per file would you like to have?"

And divide the file into the lines the user wants

Comment: It is pretty easy. a while loop with Console.WriteLine, Console.ReadLine and TryParse to get the input. And a nested loop to itterate over the files. You need to at least show us that you done any work on this before we help you any more.

Comment: Kindly check the updated question. I want a user to be able to specify the number of lines per file.

Comment: That was the original version I saw. And that is what I answered to.

Comment: I tried inserting the prompt question with Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine. It still isn't working like I want it.

Comment: Your current logic is not doing what you would expect, you need first know how many lines the user selected, do a loop using the input value as final iteration, then build the new file according the number of rows selected and so forth, what about if the remaining rows are less than input?

Comment: I have added the TryParse to ensure an integer value. Can you assist in writing a snippet. I am pretty new in .Net. That will go a long way

Comment: Take a do...while loop. One line Output. One line Input. And you use the inverted output of the TryParse to force the user to give you a valid integer.

Comment: I have done TryParse to force user to give a valid existent integer. Including with a while loop. But it just splits into a single file with only the first line now. What is the cause of that

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\COURE-TECH\source\repos\FileSplitting\FileSplitting\dnd.txt";

            var fileSuffix = 0;
            int lines = 0;


            using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("How many lines per file would you like to have?");

                    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out lines))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Write an integer value");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Done!!!");
                    }

                    string AllContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    List<string> AllNumbers = AllContent.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

                    var newLists = splitList(AllNumbers, lines);

                    foreach (var list in newLists)
                    {
                        string newFileName = $"{fileName}{(++fileSuffix)}.txt";
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(newFileName, true))
                        {
                            foreach (string phoneNumber in list)
                            {

                                tw.WriteLine(phoneNumber);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```